# AWS IAM Policy : Define the correct one

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm working on a lambda script which works */ locally only /*.

I'ld like to extend the usage of this script in another regions.
To do this, I want to update my script, so I'm starting with a :

```
print(ec2c.describe_regions())
```

When I test it, it says :

> module initialization error: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation)
>   when calling the DescribeRegions operation: You are not authorized to
>   perform this operation.

however, my policy contains ec2:DescribeRegions in the Action :

```
{
  "roleName": "ec2_scan_role",
  "policies": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "ec2:DescribeInstances",
              "ec2:StartInstances",
              "ec2:DescribeRegions",
              "ec2:StopInstances",
              "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          }
[...]
```

What's wrong?!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hum,

I found information regarding regions :

https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/1361

Maybe the root cause?

Comment: Finally it was not the cause ... and I didn't find it, but works :)